# WPF TextBlock.Text StringFormat isn't working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Name="PART_FRBold">
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="This person is:  {}{0}; {1}, {2}">
                                        <Binding Path="PersonID"/>
                                        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                                        <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
```

I can see in the ViewModel that PersonID, LastName, and FirstName are all present. But nothing actually renders to the page. The only thing I can think of is that the StringFormat is incorrect.

Comment: How are PersonID, LastName, and FirstName implemented precisely? Are there properties? Are property change notifications implemented, and if so, how? Is the VM instance you look at to check the values the very **same** ViewModel instance that the bindings bind against? Is the binding's data-context the VM instance? As you notice, the problem you describe can be down to a number of different causes, and you have to show and explain in your question how your **ViewModel class is implemented** (with respect to the properties) and how the **context for the bindings** is established and maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mikael Koskinen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949005/2819245) correctly points out that there is a problem with the format string (credit where credit is due).

The problem is not the text "*This person is:*  " in the format string, but rather the misplaced `{}` escape sequence. Thus, while Mikael's suggested solution/workaround works, it is also a bit complicated. For the format string to work, it is only required to place the escape sequence `{}` at the start of the format string:

```
StringFormat="{}This person is:  {0}; {1}, {2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated 3.3:**

The actual problem was a syntax error. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949686/66988 for the correct syntax.

For a future reference: You can use "static" parts in StringFormat, you just have to start the StringFormat with {}.

**Original incorrect answer with a workaround:**

Problem is that you can't add "This person is" inside the StringFormat property. If you remove that part:

```
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}; {1}, {2}">
                <Binding Path="PersonID"/>
                <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
```

You can see that the actual binding works.

You can get around this problem by using a static resource for the "static" part of the text and binding to it:

```
        <TextBlock.Resources>
            <system:String x:Key="MyString">This person is</system:String>
        </TextBlock.Resources>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}; {2}, {3}">
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource MyString}" />
                <Binding Path="PersonID"/>
                <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: What is the "system" namespace referred to for "system:String".

Comment: Well, `"This person is"` can be used in the format string, no need to use a static resource. But you pointed in the right direction. The actual format string should begin with the "curly brace escape" (or whatever it is really called), like `"{}This person is:  {0}; {1}, {2}"`. I completely overlooked this mistake in the format string when looking at the question...